# How to make sure SQLite database was not modified?

Tags: sqlite, security

I am looking for a way to tell if a database file was modified or not.
The amount of data stored is not large, however updates are often and running select statements after any update to create a new checksum of all data would be too much.
Previously most of our data was stored as entries with JSON, so it was much easier to get few rows and create a checksum of it. Now however, we need to use the database properly, so data will be normalized across few tables and multiple rows.
I need this to be handled by the database, so I don't want to create an md5 of the database file and check that.

Is there any way I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a database is modified, the file change counter in the [database header](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#database_header) is incremented.

Comment: In order to figure this out I would have to store this information somewhere, so when changing the database it would be sufficient to just alter this information as well.